# Offer in-app product as gift to some user in Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Is there an easy way or common pattern to follow to provide our users a way to redeem an in-app product for free?

Let me explain. Like many freemium apps, we've an in-app product that unlocks some parts of our app.

We'd like to provide our users the ability to unlock the in-app content without actually purchasing the in-app product. I know that in iOS there is some kind of license keys or coupon codes developers are using to provide such functionality.

A common example when this is useful is asking your users to translate your app in exchange of the premium version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an open source library based on the code from my other answer.

Check it out here.

https://github.com/FutureHax/UberVerificationSystem

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is nothing like this built in, you have to build this system yourself.

I have a system setup using Parse.com as a backend, storing their gmail id from the account manager, and a generated list of valid "keys" that I can send or directly associate with a users email.

Its a pain, and I really wish they would figure something out for this :(

Here is a gist with most of the relevant info. Ive gotten it to the point where its pretty much drag and drop.

https://gist.github.com/r2DoesInc/8d4a924574ec51022672

Comment: Well i thought about implementing this too. what do you need the token for? Using gmail id isn't enough?

Comment: I sell the tokens in batches occasionally, so I wont know the user. The first time a token is used the userid is attached, from then on it only works with that user.

Comment: would you mind having a conversation on hangout on this? I'm prob going to build a standard library to avoid this problem to every poor developer who wants to achieve this.